# Distance between bars with pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, bar-chart

I want to creat a ybar chart with evenly spaced bars instead like in the first example spaced by the used values. I thought using symbolic x coords could be used for this, but using this produces lots of errors like

> Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `1.0' has not been
>   define like [normalized]1.0?. ...table[x index=0, y
>   index=1]{\loadedtable};

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{
        Note Anzahl
        1.0 1
        1.3 1.3
        1.7 1.7
        2.0 2
        2.3 2.3
        2.7 2.7
        3.0 3
        3.3 3.3
        3.7 3.7
        4.0 4
        4.7 4.7
        5.0 5
    }\loadedtable

%Looks good but the spacing is wrong
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xtick=data, x=15ex, bar width=3ex,  xticklabels={{1,0},{1,3},{1,7},{2,0},{2,3},{2,7},{3,0},{3,3},{3,7},{4,0},{4,7},{5,0}},]
    \addplot[ybar] table[x index=0, y index=1]{\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

%Here the error occurs
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xtick=data, x=15ex, bar width=3ex, symbolic x coords={{1,0},{1,3},{1,7},{2,0},{2,3},{2,7},{3,0},{3,3},{3,7},{4,0},{4,7},{5,0}},]
    \addplot[ybar] table[x index=0, y index=1]{\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `symbolic x coords` has to match the input exactly, there is no `1.0` in your list of symbolic x coords. Plus I do not quite understand the values you give it.

Comment: BTW: don;t use the `minimal` class, it is not well suited for much. The `standalone` class might be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a bit improved answer from [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415422/95441) where you don't have to type explicitly every symbolic coordinate. Also there are some changes which came up after some discussion in the comments.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
    \begin{filecontents*}{Note.txt}
        Note
        1,0
        1,3
        1,7
        2,0
        2,3
        2,7
        3,0
        3,3
        3,7
        4,0
        4,7
        5,0
    \end{filecontents*}
    \begin{filecontents*}{NotenVerteilung.txt}
        Note Anzahl
        1.0 1
        1.3 1.3
        1.7 1.7
        2.0 2
        2.3 2.3
        2.7 2.7
        3.0 3
        3.3 3.3
        3.7 3.7
        4.0 4
        4.7 4.7
        5.0 5
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        x=5ex,
        ybar,
        bar width=3ex,
        xtick=data,
        % load labels from the file
        xticklabels from table={Note.txt}{Note},
    ]
        \addplot table [
            % use the index for the internal number/label
            x expr=\coordindex,
            y=Anzahl,
        ]{NotenVerteilung.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Nice, learned something new

Comment: You are both welcome :)

Comment: Is it possible to do this without changing the data in the table, like in pgfplotstable with "use comma"? Because the table is generated.

Comment: I don't think so, because `xticklabels from table` uses the data *as is*. But you can simply replace the dot in the first column by a comma after the export. If you cannot replace it in the first column only, export two lists/files, one for the `xticklabels` and one for the to plot `table/y` values.

Comment: @StefanPinnow You mean, save the generated table and then change it in an editor or by an external script, and then load the changed table?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: @baghira I normally simply have the data on disk instead of inside the latex file. `\addplot` can easily read from disk as well

Comment: @daleif The original data is in an external file. This table is generated in my Latex File on the basis of another file.

Comment: @Stefan Since this is something I have to do then in a separate step every semester I don't think I will do it! ;-) The plan is that it will be less effort than using excel.

Comment: No, it would not be, if you have the `xticklabels` in a separate (additional) file/table from where you load them. See my edited answer.

Comment: @Stefan Thats a nice idea! It still isn't a general solution on the problem that it is not possible to just switch the appearance of the values in the table, but should work for now.

Answer (score 6):

The argument to `symbolic x coords` has to be exactly the list of x input from the data. Otherwise you get the error you mention. Fix that error and it is nicely spaced as you requested.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{
        Note Anzahl
        1.0 1
        1.3 1.3
        1.7 1.7
        2.0 2
        2.3 2.3
        2.7 2.7
        3.0 3
        3.3 3.3
        3.7 3.7
        4.0 4
        4.7 4.7
        5.0 5
    }\loadedtable

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[xtick=data,
        x=5ex,
        bar width=3ex,
        symbolic x coords={1.0,1.3,1.7,2.0,2.3,2.7,3.0,3.3,3.7,4.0,4.7,5.0},
        ]
    \addplot[ybar] table[x index=0, y index=1]{\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It would be nice to just tell it to use the data spread evenly, but I have no idea how to do that, maybe others do

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to have the values with commas. So I added additionally the xticklabels like in my solution. The solution is not that nice, because if I have more values it gets very uncomfortable to add all these by hand. Anyway currently it is working.

Comment: Good solution. Very nice. +1

Answer (score 0):

This another compromise I now decided to use. Still better than using both the `symbolic x coords` and the `xticklabels`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{
        Note Anzahl
        1.0 1
        1.3 1.3
        1.7 1.7
        2.0 2
        2.3 2.3
        2.7 2.7
        3.0 3
        3.3 3.3
        3.7 3.7
        4.0 4
        4.7 4.7
        5.0 5
    }\loadedtable

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xtick=data, x=5ex, bar width=3ex, xticklabels={{1,0},{1,3},{1,7},{2,0},{2,3},{2,7},{3,0},{3,3},{3,7},{4,0},{4,7},{5,0}}]
    \addplot[ybar] table[x expr=\coordindex, y index=1]{\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It is a combination of using `xticklabels` and the solution of [Stefan Pinnow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415426/95441) by using the `x expr=\coordindex`.

Comment: But then there is no need for the "Note" column at all. Thus you can delete the column and then have to change the `y index` number to `0`.

Comment: @Stefan I am using the table for other purposes as well like in my current other question: [Build a statistic with pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415066/build-a-statistic-with-pgfplotstable)